# Website Update Tool for a Non-Programmer

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I work with my professor to implement web-based decision support tools. I am a seasoned programmer, and am at ease with the various web technologies we use. However, my professor isn't, and he usually has to rely upon me to do even the most basic tasks like adding publications and presentations to an existing list. However, he now wants to be able to do these basic tasks by himself since we both feel it will be more efficient that way, and to leave the hard-core tool implementation for me.

He suggested that we purchase Dreamweaver to achieve this. However, I do not have much experience with Dreamweaver since I prefer to work with bare HTML, CSS etc., and Emacs and Eclipse have filled these needs very well for me.

What do you think we should do? Do you think Dreamweaver will be a good tool for this? If not, is there something else we should look at? How far will he be able to get along without knowing much HTML? Do you think I should give him a crash course in HTML? Feel free to opine!

**NOTE:** The website is not based on any CMS; it is completely bred in-house. We use HTML, CSS, PHP, and JavaScript. However, my professor will most likely dealing only with HTML (no CSS etc.)

Comment: Switch over to using a CMS. This what a CMS is for.

Answer (score 3):

For these types, I often (while cringing) reach for WordPress.

If your customers can make a Facebook post, they can edit content in WordPress.  Just stay on top of the updates for it, as exploits for WordPress are found with very high frequency.  Even with this maintenance, it will still be easier than doing updates for them.

It shouldn't be too hard to convert your site over to a template that you can use within WordPress.  If you can't, you can easily embed content from WordPress into your site via feeds, but there is a performance penalty for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the site with Dreamweaver, [Adobe Contribute](http://www.adobe.com/products/contribute.html) is a good option that is pretty much WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get), and it is designed to work with Dreamweaver templates.

Basically, it helps prevent novices from screwing up the site too badly by locking users out of template areas (the areas that are supposed to stay the same from page to page, such as navigation).